# Can I enable native bridge on x86 cuttlefish

Tags: android, android-build

I want to run arm apps on x86 cuttlefish.
I found the native_support and binary_translation in frameworks/libs.
But I don't know how to enable it,or it can'nt be enable on cuttlefish?

I try to set `enable=true` in `native_birdge_support/Android.mk`,but it can not be compile,conflict with other packages.
And I found `enable_riscv64_to_x86_64.mk` in binary_translation/Android.mk,

```
include frameworks/libs/binary_translation/berberis_config.mk

PRODUCT_PACKAGES += \
    $(BERBERIS_PRODUCT_PACKAGES) \
    $(BERBERIS_PRODUCT_PACKAGES_RISCV64_TO_X86_64)

# ATTENTION: we are overriding
# PRODUCT_SYSTEM_PROPERTIES += ro.dalvik.vm.native.bridge?=0
# set by build/make/target/product/runtime_libart.mk
PRODUCT_SYSTEM_PROPERTIES += \
    ro.dalvik.vm.native.bridge=libberberis_riscv64.so

PRODUCT_SYSTEM_PROPERTIES += \
    ro.dalvik.vm.isa.riscv64=x86_64 \
    ro.enable.native.bridge.exec=1

PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES += frameworks/libs/native_bridge_support/libc

PRODUCT_ARTIFACT_PATH_REQUIREMENT_ALLOWED_LIST += \
    $(BERBERIS_DISTRIBUTION_ARTIFACTS_RISCV64)

BUILD_BERBERIS := true
BUILD_BERBERIS_RISCV64_TO_X86_64 := true
```

is it an example? I don't know how to use it.

Thks a lot!!!!!!!

Comment: native_bridge is not use to arm_x86 translation,it's for risc....